# Фрэймворк для работы с HTTP

Tags: http, java, framework

Привет всем.
Народ, подскажите, пожалуйста, Java библиотеку для отсылки/принятия запросов по HTTP. Интересует аналог по типу класса https://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/source/browse/branches/khartn/http.php которой можно было бы передавать запросы в виде

```
Args: 
Array
(
    [Protocol] => http
    [HostName] => ihtika.googlecode.com
    [Headers] => Array
        (
            [Host] => ihtika.googlecode.com
            [User-Agent] => phpsvnclient (http://phpsvnclient.googlecode.com/)
            [Authorization] =>  Basic Og==
            [Content-Type] => text/xml
            [Depth] => 1
            [Content-Length] => 202
        )

    [HostPort] => 0
    [RequestURI] => /svn/!svn/bc/158/trunk/src/com/google/code/ihtika/IhtikaClient/MainThread.java/
    [RequestMethod] => REPORT
    [Body] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <S:log-report xmlns:S="svn:"> <S:start-revision>0</S:start-revision><S:end-revision>100</S:end-revision><S:path></S:path><S:discover-changed-paths/></S:log-report>
)
```

Т. е. с возможностью формировать headers, указывать RequestMethod и добавлять Request Body.
Глядел в сторону http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/, но не увидел там такой возможности...

Answer (score 4):

Все это, конечно, возможно в HttpClient, иначе он не был бы таким популярным.

Вот пример работы с POST:

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://jakarata.apache.org/");
NameValuePair[] data = {
  new NameValuePair("user", "joe"),
  new NameValuePair("password", "bloggs")
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
// execute method and handle any error responses.
...
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// handle response.
```

Как видите, мы устанавливаем и метод и тело запроса. О применении различных методов написано [здесь](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods.html).

Для установки заголовков воспользуйтесь соответствующим методом `HttpMethod.addRequestHeader`

ЗЫ. JavaDoc - наше все. http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/overview-summary.html

ЗЫЫ. Кроме того есть официальные примеры [здесь](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/).

---

По вновь открывшимся обстоятельствам, меняю ответ. Видимо вам нужно что-то вроде [Apache Jackrabbit WebDAV Library](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html).

Comment: А данные примеры будут ли работать с httpclient-4.1.1? Что-то я не вижу в httpclient-4.1.1.jar класса 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod
Ведь мне нужен именно GET, а не POST.
И, как быть в том случае, когда GET запрос выполнит GET запрос, а в моём случае нужно выполнить REPORT запрос... Как заменить GET на [RequestMethod] => REPORT?

Comment: То есть вам нужен GET-запрос, у которого будет еще и body?

И если не сложно, подскажите, что это за REPORT запрос. Не припоминаю такого в стандарте HTTP.

UPD. Все, понял что вы хотите. Для поддержки REPORT вам нужна реализация не HTTP-клиента, a WebDAV. Ищите в эту сторону.

Comment: А какие JAVA WebDAV клиенты поддерживают отсылку запросов? К примеру, sardine предоставляет только стандартный набор функций типа move copy и т.д. Каким клиентом можно послать нужный мне запрос?

Comment: Вопрос решил.
Спасибо Nofate за наводку.
Решил с использованием httpclient-4.1.1.
Пришлось проанализировать другой программный продукт для решения задачи...